# How to configure Jenkins/Hudson to Use LDAP on Snow Leopard Server

Tags: ldap, hudson, osx-snow-leopard, jenkins

We run jenkins on a mac mini server and need to have it use OpenDirectory. (I took this up again after getting Nexus to work with OD.)

I went into the Manage Jenkins tab, opened up the LDAP config panel and it attempts to connect, but I am getting an error that it can't connect. I am trying to just supply a username and password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the reason I couldn't connect was the Manager DN has to be the complete FQ name, e.g. uid=root,cn=users,dc=ontometrics,dc=com.

Once I got that working, I was getting LDAP Error 49: bad credentials. To solve this, I found a great LDAP browser that installed in a few minutes on the mini server: [LDAP Manager](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/29558/ldapmanager). That helped me see the FQN for the root account.

One last thing: once I had the right account, it auth'ed, but then on saving the settings, I got an ERROR 500. Turned out, that was because I had a few spaces in the FQN, so do not do dc=ontometrics, dc=com. Then it worked and I logged in!

BTW, the mini server with 8 GBs of RAM runs Jenkins beautifully.